# combine rows into one row in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

let's say I have:

```
User     Email
 1       abc@email.com
 1       efg@email.com
 1       xyz@email.com
 2       aaa@email.com
 2       bbb@email.com
 3       ccc@email.com
```

and I want the output:

```
 User     Eamil1            Email2          Email3
 1        abc@email.com     efg@email.com   xyz@email.com
 2        aaa@email.com     bbb@email.com   
 3        ccc@email.com
```

I found other answers about using FOR XML Path, but that's not what I want. it combines rows into one column, and separate the values with ';'

I also tried JOIN the table with itself, and it's also not the result I want.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: May I ask what is your intention for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. Pivot is not a good solution in this case. Pivot is not efficient for non numeric values.

```
WITH C AS(
    SELECT 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY Email) AS [Rank]
    ,[User], Email
    FROM Emails
)
SELECT [User]
    ,MIN(CASE C.[Rank] WHEN 1 THEN Email END) AS [Email1]
    ,MIN(CASE C.[Rank] WHEN 2 THEN Email END) AS [Email2]
    ,MIN(CASE C.[Rank] WHEN 3 THEN Email END) AS [Email3]
FROM C
GROUP BY [User]
```

Comment: What do you mean pivot is not efficient for non numerical values?

Comment: i will give this a try. i did some research on pivot. pivot mostly works well if you need to SUM/AVG int values on results. I haven't been able to get a way to make it work on email addresses yet.

Comment: @triston You can use PIVOT on an an email address, you'll just need to use the aggregate function `max` or `min` on the column since it is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the PIVOT command.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php